# PineScript Set Stop loss to entry candle ATR band

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

Trying to set my stop loss to the entry candles ATR band but it keeps recalculating it every new candle.  So the Stop loss isnt triggered until much later than it should be since its setting it to the previous candle from the current one.

```
    //@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay = true)
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 200)

bf=ema1>ema2
sf=ema1<ema2
buy=  bf
sell= sf

[macdline, signalline, macdhist] = ta.macd(close, 8, 21, 5)
rsi1 = ta.rsi(close, 13)
rsi2 = ta.rsi(close, 5)

ema3 = ta.ema(close, 5)
ema4 = ta.ema(close, 11)
ema5 = ta.ema(close, 13)
sma = ta.sma(close, 36)

length = 100
spike = close - open
x = ta.stdev(spike,length)
y = ta.stdev(spike,length) * -1

buy1 = ta.crossover(macdline, signalline)
buy2 = rsi1>50
buy3 = rsi2>50
buy4 = ema3 > ema4
buy5 = ema5 > sma
buy6 = spike > x

sell1 = ta.crossunder(macdline, signalline)
sell2 = rsi1 < 50
sell3 = rsi2 < 50
sell4 = ema3 < ema4
sell5 = ema5 < sma
sell6 = spike < y

atrPeriod = 14
srcUpper = close
srcLower = close
atrMultiplierUpper = 1
atrMultiplierLower = 1

atr1 = ta.atr(atrPeriod)

atrupper1 = srcUpper + atr1 * atrMultiplierUpper
atrlower1 = srcLower - atr1 * atrMultiplierLower
atrupper = atrupper1
atrlower = atrlower1

if (buy and buy1 and buy2 and buy3 and buy4 and buy5 and buy6)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

strategy.exit("Close Buy", profit= 50 , stop = atrlower)

if (sell and sell1 and sell2 and sell3 and sell4 and sell5 and sell6)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

strategy.exit("Close Sell", profit = 50 , stop = atrupper)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    atrupper1 = srcUpper + atr1[1] * atrMultiplierUpper
atrlower1 = srcLower - atr1[1] * atrMultiplierLower
```

That "[1]" indicates the bar index, likes an array, so [0] is the current bar, [1] last bar, [2] last second bar ecc.

Idk if should be:

```
atrupper1 = srcUpper[1] + atr1[1] * atrMultiplierUpper
atrlower1 = srcLower[1] - atr1[1] * atrMultiplierLower
```

Try both.